# Assign a stored function to create_thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I created a class `CThread` which should be the base class to many other classes and contain the thread related code.

In `CThread` I have a variable:

```
int (*m_fpRun)() = 0;
```

Here `CThread` is inherited by class `CTemp` and `m_fpRun` is assigned procedure `CTemp::Run()`

I tried to assign the function to

```
iRetVal = pthread_create(&m_sThreadID,
                         m_pAttr,
                         &m_fpRun,
                         m_pArg);
```

But I always get this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (**)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
                            m_pArg);
```

Comment: Why are you not using [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)?

Comment: Show us your code.  ala [mcve]

Comment: Although C++ is world-famous for its incomprehensible and confusing error messages, this isn't one of them. This is probably one of the most simplest error messages you can get. As the error message says: the third argument must be a value that has a specific type, and a value of a completely different type gets passed in. This is true of every function in C++ and not only pthread_create. Parameter value types must match, within certain boundaries, like implicit conversions between integers (of varying sizes), floats, etc. None of that applies here. Which part of this error is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can't do what you are trying.  Your `m_fpRun` variable is simply the wrong type for what `pthread_create()` is expecting.  And if it were the right type, then you couldn't assign a *non-static* class method to it.

In short, you simply cannot use a *non-static* class method as the `pthread` callback.  You need to use an intermediate stand-alone function or *static* class method, and then that can call your target function as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class CThread
{
private:
    pthread_t m_sThreadID;
    pthread_attr_t *m_pAttr = nullptr;

    static void* StaticRun(void *arg)
    {
        CThread *pThis = (CThread*) arg;
        int iRetVal = pThis->m_fpRun();
        ...
        return nullptr; 
    }

protected:
    std::function<int()> m_fpRun;

public:
    void Start()
    {
        int iRetVal = pthread_create(&m_sThreadID,
                                     m_pAttr,
                                     &StaticRun,
                                     this);
        ...
    }
};

class CTemp : public CThread
{
private:
    int Run()
    {
        ...
    }

public:
    CTemp()
    {
        m_fpRun = [this](){ return this->Run(); };
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you should use a `virtual` method instead of a function-pointer variable, eg:

```cpp
class CThread
{
private:
    pthread_t m_sThreadID;
    pthread_attr_t *m_pAttr = nullptr;

    static void* StaticRun(void *arg)
    {
        CThread *pThis = (CThread*) arg;
        int iRetVal = pThis->Run();
        ...
        return nullptr; 
    }

protected:
    virtual int Run() = 0;

public:
    void Start()
    {
        int iRetVal = pthread_create(&m_sThreadID,
                                     m_pAttr,
                                     &StaticRun,
                                     this);
        ...
    }
};

class CTemp : public CThread
{
private:
    int Run() override
    {
        ...
    }

public:
    CTemp() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is correct :-)

The 3rd argument of `pthread_create` is `void * (*)(void *)`
(a pointer to a function taking a pointer to `void` as a parameter and returning a pointer to `void`)

Your argument is of type `int (**)()`
(pointer to a pointer to a function taking nothing as parameter and returning an `int`)

In a nutshell : there is no way to transform a value to a pointer for the return type and no way of transforming nothing to a pointer to void for the argument.

You must change `m_pfRun`.